# react-navigation go Back not navigate to previous screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using new react-navigation 2.16.0 in my react-native app.

I have welcome (login and register) screen and then Main stack. main stack include all screens after success auth(login\register).

```
MainStack = createStackNavigator(
            {
                Welcome: {
                    screen: Welcome, navigationOptions: {
                        gesturesEnabled: false,
                    }
                },
                Main: {
                    screen: App, navigationOptions: {
                        gesturesEnabled: false,
                    }
                }



            }, {
                headerMode: 'none',
                lazy: true,
                initialRouteName: UserStore.token ? 'Main' : 'Welcome',
                gesturesEnabled: false,
                cardStack: {
                    gesturesEnabled: false
                },
                cardStyle: {
                    elevation: 0,
                    shadowOpacity: 0,
                    borderBottomWidth: 0,
                    borderTopWidth: 0

                },
                transitionConfig: () => ({
                    containerStyle: {
                        elevation: 0,
                        shadowOpacity: 0,
                        borderBottomWidth: 0,
                        borderTopWidth: 0
                    }
                }),
            }
        )`
```

Main stack render

```
render() {


    // const splashDone = this.state.splashDone && this.state.backSplash
    const ready = UserStore.storeHydrated

    console.log('Current Routes', NavigationStore)
    // console.log('AppStore.loading ', AppStore.loading)
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1,backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
        <StatusBar
            barStyle="light-content"
        />
            {!splashDone ? <SplashScreen /> : null}

            {ready &&
                <Provider {...stores}>

                    <MainStack 

                    />

                </Provider>}

            <InternetConnectionPopUp />

            {AppStore.loading ?
                <Spinner
                    color={colors.yellow}
                    style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0, left: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0, zIndex: 99999 }} />
                : null}

            <View style={Platform.OS === 'ios' && this.state.flag ? { height: calcSize(25) } : {}} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BackHandler, Alert, AppState, View,Keyboard } from 'react-native'
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react/native'
import { AppStack } from '../../routes'
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import { Header } from '../../components';
let popupOpen = false

@inject('AppStore') @observer
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            appState: AppState.currentState,
            nowMounted: false

        }
        this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this)

    }

    goBack() {
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ nowMounted: true })
    }






    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Header  onPressBack={this.goBack}/>
                <AppStack/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

AppStack.js

```
import {
    Dashboard,
    Services,
    Schedule,
    ScheduleDays,
    ScheduleTime,
    CancelAppointment
} from '../screens'
import { createStackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

export const AppStack = createStackNavigator({

    Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard, navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    } },

    Services: { screen: Services, navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    } },
    Schedule: { screen: Schedule, navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    } },
    ScheduleDays: { screen: ScheduleDays, navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    } },
    ScheduleTime: { screen: ScheduleTime, navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    } },
    CancelAppointment: { screen: CancelAppointment, navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    } },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
    lazy: true,
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    cardStack: {
        gesturesEnabled: false
    },

})
```

goBack not works in createStackNavigator, it stay in same screen.
go Back not works at all.
when I navigate from dashboard to services screen and then press onBack in services it do nothing.
I also tried to change instead of createStackNavigator to createSwitchNavigator but still it not works.

Comment: I doubt whether `onBackPress` of `Header` component is called or not? Put some log or alert and check

Comment: yes, for sure. I did console.log and and it's called.

Answer (score 12):

Could you please put the code of the service screen where you call the goBack function, it could be helpful.
Generally you just call

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

or

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
```

you can also try

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
```

if it's in the history of the stack it will go back to the previous screen from service screen instead of pushing it on top

Comment: If your answer is not a full answer, but rather a commend, please use the comment option instead.

Comment: just joined the platform, i can't comment others post until I have 50 reputation, but thanks for the precisation

Answer (score 5):

This work for me.

```
  <Button
      title="go back"
      onPress={(props) => { this.props.navigation.goBack(null) }}
  />
```

Dont forget to remove `this` for functional component.

Answer (score 1):

Functional Component Approach

```
import {StyleSheet,Text,View,TouchableOpacity,} from 'react-native';

const ScreenName = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <Text>
             GoBack
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
     flex:1,
     display: 'flex',
     justifyContent:'center',   
     alignItems: 'center',
    }
});

export default ScreenName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation prop has a goBack helper.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the home screen of the app</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => goBack()}
          title="Go to Brent's profile"
        />
      </View>
     )
   }
}
```